# How to add space between the Bootstrap 4 navbar links?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I created a navbar with Bootstrap 4, and I want to add a bit more space between the navbar items on the right.

```html
<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top">
  <div class="site-branding navbar-brand container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="#"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link menu-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link menu-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link menu-link" href="#">Work</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link menu-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .site-branding -->
</nav>
```

I tried to add padding and margin horizontally to the .menu-link class, but there are not any changes.

https://github.com/jvjames97/Boostrap-4-Navbar/blob/master/HTML5

I would like to add 20 px more between the navbar elements.

Comment: Try adding the margin/padding to `nav-item`

Comment: *"I tried to add padding and margin horizontally to the .menu-link class, but there are not any changes"* .. this seems to work fine: https://www.codeply.com/go/sIzIvx8BWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css to the code

```
.nav-item {
 margin-right: 20px;
 }
```